# Track back button event

Tags: android

Precise event control back of the phone, I researched and discovered the method `onBackPressed ()`, but from what I understand, I have to manually make the transition back from the screens ... anyone have any suggestions on how to make by clicking on the back, back to the previous screen?

My app has 4 activities, as I do, for example: I am in Activity 2 and it got four layouts, and I'm currently using the third layout at runtime, as you would to go back to the second layout?

If you do not have a suggestion, I'm also wanting to know how to get the layout that is in use at runtime

Thanks.

Comment: onBackPressed () must works ...whats your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create hierarchal parent activities and allow the action bar to provide up navigation.

here is a tutorial that should help you out.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear on what you require, but...

You don't have to manually do the transitions back from screens, because onBackButton() is already doing the work for you:

> public void onBackPressed ()
>
> Added in API level 5
> Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity, but you can override this to do whatever you want.

If you want to customize this, you can override onBackButton():

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     //do your stuff

     //optional, if you want the default behaviour of back button to be called,
     //that is going back to previous activity
     super.onBackPressed(); 
}
```